# Complication Image is White Box - watchOS 2 ClockKit

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch, watchos-2

I'm trying to get an image to show up as a complication on the Apple Watch face. I've tried both .jpg and .png files. I believe the code in terms to get the complication working is correct, but for some reason the image comes out white like so:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
var template: CLKComplicationTemplate? = nil

let temporaryTemplate = CLKComplicationTemplateModularSmallSimpleImage()
let theImage = UIImage(named: "testImage")!.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)

let imager = CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: theImage)
temporaryTemplate.imageProvider = imager

template = temporaryTemplate
```

I know the images are treated as "alpha-only" for complications but I thought that was automatically done by the system. Am I missing a step here?

Answer (score 5):

You're right everything is correct with your code and the evidence is the white square it means that the question is in the image.

Just watch [the video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-209/) carefully starting from 12:10. In a nutshell you have to create a monochrome png image with the alpha-channel and the system of course cannot do it for you. Below is the example, you just can put it instead of your image and see the result:

[image]

Also please attach your image to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the images for complication as mentioned in the guideline. and below is my code. It works fine for me, remove the rendering mode part and try. I have attached a sample image i used.[image]

```
    let template = CLKComplicationTemplateModularLargeStandardBody()
    let image = UIImage(named: imageName[![enter image description here][1]][1])

    template.headerImageProvider =
        CLKImageProvider(onePieceImage: image!)
    template.headerTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: headerText)
```

Comment: That's great but what about the images I was using? Why don't those images specifically work?

Comment: Yes the issue is with the image and system won't do the any image modification.Use monochrome image with alpha channel only.. Go through this link for complication image guideline for further information https://developer.apple.com/watch/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/

Answer (score 0):

I confess I won't watch WWDC videos or read Apple docs... 
I try things and it usually works.

So after seeing this bug, and playing with image, I had an idea that panned out. I have to return time line entry even if I don't support going forward or back.

And it solved the problem of white box image appearing instead of the app icon.

```
- (void)getCurrentTimelineEntryForComplication:(CLKComplication *)complication
                               withHandler:(void(^)(CLKComplicationTimelineEntry * __nullable))handler {
[self getLocalizableSampleTemplateForComplication:complication
                                      withHandler:^(CLKComplicationTemplate * _Nullable complicationTemplate) {
                                          CLKComplicationTimelineEntry* entry = [CLKComplicationTimelineEntry entryWithDate:[NSDate date]
                                                                                                       complicationTemplate:complicationTemplate];
                                          handler(entry);
                                      }];}
```